# Changing Display color of PNG with transparency in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some PNGs with transparency that I use for buttons in my WPF/C# application.
Right now I have two versions of each PNG, one for normal view and one for hover, each a different color.  However, I would really like to just have one single PNG and maybe make everything that's not transparent white (each image is all one color, no detail other than shape. 
Would it be possible to then alter the color of each using a SolidColorBrush or similar and create the Normal/Hover versions as a static resource in my XAML?
Something like this:

```
<Image Key="BtnMenu" Source="Images/Menu.png" Fill="ButtonNormalBrush" />
<Image Key="BtnMenuHover" Source="Images/Menu.png" Fill="ButtonHoverBrush" />
```

Yeah, I totally made up the "Fill" thing...
But the basic idea is that I have a ResourceDictionary that contains the color scheme that is used throughout the entire application, which makes it so that I can change any of the about 6 colors I use in the application in one place and it updates on every control that references that color... but the one place I cannot do it is those PNGs for the buttons. (Ideally in the future I'll make that ResourceDictionary something that can be loaded in at runtime to make the application have alternate "skins"..but right now the PNGs keep me from doing that).

**Edit:** BTW, if the solution requires a Converter or something written in code, that's totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... If you created a Grid, and put the Image inside that Grid, you could set the Background of the Grid to your fill color.

Edit: Here is some code:

```
<Button>
    <Grid Background="SkyBlue">
        <Image Source="img.png" Stretch="None" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: Quoting the question, "make everything that's **not** transparent white". Your answer does not cater to that.

Comment: Oops, I feel dumb. The only thing I can think of is to use Geometries and forget about the PNG. But that might be too complex.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to apply a [`ShaderEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect.aspx) as the [`Effect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.effect.aspx) on the hover image or create a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which transforms your image. Another possibility would be to encapsulate such logic in a subclass of `Image`.

Comment: I'm decent with WPF but still pretty new to it... examples would be appreciated.

Comment: @AdamHaile: Well, if you want to convert pixels you could use [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx), i cannot really give you an example as it is a pain to use and it depends on your file's format, haven't used it in years myself.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752364.aspx
You can simply create ImageSource with new Format-object from another ImageSource. Format object specifies color mask for an Image.